# C# WPF Как добавить attached контрол в свой User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть свой User Control. Как вложить в него например TextBlock как ето сделано в ScrollViewer?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это обычные Attached Properties, никакой контрол таким образом не вкладывается в ScrollViewer.

Comment: @АндрейNOP т.е. attached property типа TextBlock?

Comment: Нет. AP внутри класса `TextBlock`: [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock?view=netframework-4.7.2#поля)